# Joomla session not passed to custom component

Tags: custom-component, session

So I'm having trouble with a Joomla (version 3.6.4) project that I need to solve for my work.

The problem is that whenever I log in on my homepage, I get logged out when going to my custom component page. Here are some scenario's

- When I log in on my joomla homepage, I can go to the basic pages like contact or about me, and the problem occurs whenever I want to go to a custom component page.
- When I log in on my joomla homepage, and go to a category of my custom component page, I have to log in again. When I log in on that specific category page and go to my homepage it seems alright..
- If i log in on category page A and go back to my homepage, I get logged out when I click on category page B. So I need to sign in again on category page B. When I do that, I have access to homepage, category page A and category page B, but nog category page C.

So basically, I need to sign in on every category page on my custom component to keep browsing on my website. It does not pass along the user credentials to other pages that are available in my custom component.

Is this a session refresh error? or some sort of custom override method in the component that needs to be turned off?

please help, since I have been spending my entire morning trying to figure out.

Comment: Try to check if you're staying within one sub-domain. If you go from www to non-www and vice-versa you'll be logged out.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment on your question stated, check if you're going from www to non-www. However, I would say that this is not the problem, since you are having the problem more than twice (Category A, B, and C).

The Joomla session is very delicate yet reliable when left alone, so this means that you are, in your component, modifying the Joomla session in some way, or you are accessing the Joomla session in a wrong way.

Check your lines of code that have to do with the session, or, better yet, share your component here, many are eager to help!